# System.IO.FileInfo works OK in Visual Studio 2008 but not in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I have recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012.

I am working with an old (and complex) code and the upgrade went surprisingly well, except for this very function:

```
FI = New System.IO.FileInfo("X:\MyFolder\MyFile.sim")
```

(in which "X:\" is a mapped external drive)

- In Visual Studio 2008: *FI.Exists* is **True**
- In Visual Studio 2012: *FI.Exists* is **False**

I am pretty confused about that. Does anybody have a clue about how could I attack this problem?

Comment: Did your `TargetFramework` change from VS2008 to VS2012? E.G. Are you still targetting `NET20` or `NET30` in VS2012?

Comment: Are you running VS2008 or VS2012 as administrator, and not the other? When you run as admin, you don't have the same mapped network drives in your session...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque : I tried running VS2012 as an admin and it didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @TheGreatCO : nice, my projects are now automatically targeting NET4.0 (after the VS2008->VS2012 automatic conversion), while in VS2008 I was using NET3.5. I have changed that [through this HowTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202(v=vs.110).aspx), but now this change has a side-effect: my project is unable to find the classes in other projects (from the same solution) after the build, and changing these other projects to NET3.5 doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @Tremor That's not what Thomas asked. He was not suggesting you run VS2012 as an administrator - he was stating that your mapped drives would not be available ***if*** you run as administrator.

Comment: @RB Ah ok thanks, I'll test both ways right away and I will answer in TheGreatCO's post since he is suggesting the same method and others.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, nothing has changed between `NET20` and `NET45` with respect to what causes `System.IO.FileInfo.Exists` to return `false`.  This being said, `Exists` can return false under any of the following conditions:

- The file does not exist.
- The Path does not exist.
- The executing assembly does not have permission to access the file.

  - The user executing the assembly does not have permission
  - The assembly is executing in a user scope that does not have permission. (eg, run as administrator).
- The Path contains invalid characters.
- The Path is null.
- The Path cannot be reached (eg, the network drive has disconnected).

With this information in hand, you should try running your code in different environments.  Such as:

- With or without running VS as administrator
- Running the executable directly (outside of VS)
- Using a tool such as LINQPad to run a script form of the code: `var FI = new System.IO.FileInfo("X:\MyFolder\MyFile.sim");`

Another path you can take is debugging this is to run it against a known file that exists on the local machine.  For example, test if a file on your desktop exists in both runtimes.  Although I strongly suspect this has something to do with the network drive disconnecting while idle.  You can also try bypassing the mapped drive and go directly to the full path (eg \some-server\MyFolder\MyFile.sim) and see if that throws an exception or some other kind of result.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. Today, one day later, and without rebooting the machine, it works. I can't figure it out, I did nothing that could change the situation: the target framework is still NET40 etc. But before that, I tested all of the conditions under which "Exists" return false (see next comment).

Comment: 1 and 2: the file or path did exist. 3.1 and 3.2: I had access to the file as a user (since I could use the explorer to access to it), and running VB2012 as administrator or not didn't change the result (FileInfo.Exists was still false). 4: it did not contain any invalid character. 5: Path was not null. 6: the drive was connected. I did not do the other tests, and now that it is working I will not be able to to them (sorry if anybody else has the same problem and finds this post).

Comment: @Tremor network drives can experience intermittent issues like this. I could not tell you why, but I have seen inconsistent results like this before. I suspect it is some sort of issue related to cached connections. Glad it's working for you.

Comment: VS running NOT as Administrator has done the trick! On the other hand, while working with WCF-Services locally, VS must be started in Administaror-Mode...weird M$-Stuff around here!!!